# how to support all screen size ? any new method? manifest code?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am using old method to support all screen size like,

layout directories

layout-small,
layout-normal,
layout-large,
layout-xlarge

value directories

value-small,
value-normal,
value-large
value-xlarge

this method small is working efficiently but 320*480 pixel mobile is take large screen size and the code in device is broken. I am not write any code in manifest to support the screen sizes.

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

- To declare the screen sizes your application supports, you should include the

> supports-screens

element in your manifest file.

- Alternative drawables

Answer (score 0):

To specify which screen size your app supports define

**supports-screens**
 tag in manifest.

To better support different dp screens use ***swdp*** configuration like this:
**layout-sw600dp**/

Comment: I use the layout format like layout-sw320dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp but in 320dp the code is broken .. please show me an example

Comment: Hi, There is nothing special about code. All you need to do is put your desired layout in respective layout folders. Even then if you feel it doesn't work then the issue is probably in resources. Although android will automatically resize resources but it's not perfect. Do you have drawables-ldpi, drawables-mdpi folders ? Similarly for mipmap or you can use svg resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
             <supports-screens
              android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

For more information go through the following link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#resizeable